# Unable to debug Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, debugging, windows-services

I was looking into several posts in order to find how to debug a Windows Service.
I've found that if I put the following code in my `OnStart()` function:

```
Debugger.Launch();
```

would do the trick, but after I start my windows service via the CMD (NET START), it just starts and runs properly but the debugger never launches, even though the VS is opened with the loaded windows service.

I feel like I'm missing something, what is it?

Comment: Maybe you can integrate [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) to assist you in debugging your windows service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing that by modifing service's Main method, it's in the Program.cs and by default it looks like this :

```
ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new ServiceMain() };
ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

you can then use [Environment.UserInteractive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userinteractive.aspx) to find out is your service started like a service or trough debugger :

```
if (!Environment.UserInteractive)
{
  ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
  ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new ServiceMain() };
  ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
else
{
  ServiceMain sm = new ServiceMain();
  Console.Write("Service debug run");
  sm.StartForDebugging();
}
```

Of course you will have to add StartForDebugging method in your service and do practically the same like you do in OnStart method, or you could call OnStart method directly just make it public.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to include this in the `OnStart` method:

```
while(!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Then, manually attach to the process from the Visual Studio menu: *Debug - > Attach to Process*.

Also, please note that in the *Remarks* section of the [Debugger.Launch Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx) topic is stated that:

> If a debugger is already attached, nothing happens.

Comment: Which process? My service?

Comment: Yes, your service's process.

Comment: My service's process is grayed (I cannot click it).

Comment: So it means that you already have a debugger attached to it. You have to run the service without debugging.

Comment: Ah, if I start it from NET START it would be without the debugger, no?

Comment: I have no idea how to run the service without debugging. I simply start the service via NET START, and it's just grayed

Comment: It might be a permissions problem.  Are you a local admin with full rights to the system?  If not, I'd suggest starting there.